# The reason behind ControlToBoxes (DynamicDump`)

Tags: programming, gui-construction, code-review

## Background

I'm trying to establish best practices for custom controllers programming. This question is about one top level aspect of it.

WRI suggested (few talks I don't remember right now) to follow e.g. `LabeledSliders` setup. Let's take a look at definitions of `LabeledSlider` then:

```
Needs @ "GeneralUtilities`"
PrintDefinitions @ LabeledSlider
```

and follow them. Here are steps you will face

1. Evaluation: `LabeledSlider` `DownValues`

   Set of definitions to convert `LabeledSlider[...]:=` to valid form, basic validation for e.g. range specification is performed etc.

   At the end a valid, inert, `LabeledSlider[...]` is produced, ready for conversion to boxes.
2. Typesetting: `LabeledSlider` `UpValues+MakeBoxes`

   ```
   LabeledSlider /: MakeBoxes[c_LabeledSlider, fmt]:= (... ControlToBoxes[c, fmt] )
   ```
3. **Typesetting: `ControlToBoxes` `DownValues` evaluation**

   It handles basic syntactic sugar for the controller. Decides what to do with respect of the first argument, `_Dynamic` or `_?NumericQ`

   At the end it governs interpretation to `InputForm` by setting up `Interpretation`.

   ```
   ControlToBoxes[LabeledSlider[...] := With[
    {grid = RawBoxes @ labeledSliderBoxes[...]},
     MakeBoxes[
      Interpretation[  gird,   LabeledSlider[...]],
      fmt
     ]
   ];
   ```

4. Typesetting: `labeledSliderBoxes` evaluation (specific/low level definitions)

   Creates the controller boxes from specification, e.g. assembles event handlers, bitmaps etc etc.

## The question

I don't understand point 3. Why do we need a symbol which shares definitions for all possible GUI elements?

`ControlToBoxes // PrintDefinitions` contains a lot.

Which means that if you follow this convention for custom controllers and then will try to e.g. `SaveDefinitions` of `mySlider` or whatever, you will collect a bunch of unrelated code.

Can't we have e.g. `{controllerName}InterpretationBoxes` convention for step 3? This way each controller has independent set of definitions.

I don't see any special advantages, only problems with it.

Maybe they do this out of habit and because mma dependencies are always there anyway. This is what I think is the case but want to make sure I didn't miss anything stupid since the struggle is real and they suggest to follow this scheme.

Comment: Just a wild guess (didn't look into it in too much detail): Could it have to do with ``DynamicDump`toggleControlMakeBoxes``? That seems to be used to redefine what `ControlToBoxes` does, no idea where it's used though

Comment: @Mathe172 maybe, I'm not sure what it is for (versioning, version switch?). Otoh those definitions seem to handle specific `sym` not `ControlToBoxes` definitions in bulk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I recall, we architected things this way mainly so that FormatValues[LabeledSlider] would remain simple and consistent across all built-in control generators. We follow a similar pattern for other built-in box generators (like Grid, Row, ...).

I can't think of any reason for you to use DynamicDump`ControlToBoxes when typesetting your own custom controls. You should either define the FormatValues directly in "Step 2", or call your own utility that constructs the boxes for a particular case, depending on how you want to modularize your code.

Note that SaveDefinitions is not an issue for built-in controls, because built-in controls are Protected and ReadProtected. That makes them invisible to SaveDefinitions.

We don't typically bother to protect symbols in *Dump` or *Private` contexts, as their context name alone should warn you against calling them directly. Such symbols are, by definition, an internal implementation detail, and so referring to them directly from any other body of code is almost always a mistake.